# How to add a class after element reaches some point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I know this has been asked a thousand times, but I can't get this to work.
I'm trying to get an aside to show up after the page has been scrolled 500px.
I'm fairly new to javascript, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing. Any help getting this working would be great!

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    // find the id with class 'active' and remove it
    $(".work-col-1-2").removeClass("visible");
    // get the amount the window has scrolled
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    // add the 'active' class to the correct id based on the scroll amount
    if (scroll <= 500) {
        $(".work-col-1-2").addClass("visible");
    }
});
```

```css
.work-col-1-2 {
    position: fixed;
    right: 6%;
    top: 0;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: -1;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.work-col-1-2.visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="container">
    <div class="work-col-1-2">
        <p>Text here.</p>
    </div>
</div><!-- end of container div-->
```

Comment: Do you have any errors or why you thinking your script dont work

Comment: You have two script tags. Remove one

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have change

```
if (scroll <= 500) {
   $(".work-col-1-2").addClass("visible");
}
```

to

```
if (scroll >= 500) {
    $(".work-col-1-2").addClass("visible");
}
```

also you have 2 script tags. Remove one.

Answer (score 0):

You have two classes, .work-col-1-2 and .work-col-1-2.visible
If you want to add a class called visible you should only use a class called visible.

```
.work-col-1-2 {
position: fixed;
right: 6%;
top: 0;
width: 25%;
padding: 1%;
margin: 0;
display: inline-block;
box-sizing: border-box;
z-index: -1;
visibility: hidden;
}

.visible {
visibility: visible;
}
```

Your code is fine but is looking for objects with the class name .work-col-1-2 and then adding the visible class which can't find. So changing the name of the class should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example for you. All of your selectors are wrong. You have to use `#` as `id` selector and `.` as `class` selector.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    // find the id with class 'active' and remove it
    $("#work-col-1-2").removeClass("visible");
    // get the amount the window has scrolled
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    // add the 'active' class to the correct id based on the scroll amount
    if (scroll >= 500) {
        $("#work-col-1-2").addClass("visible");
    }
});
```

```css
#work-col-1-2 {
    position: fixed;
    right: 6%;
    top: 0;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: -1;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#work-col-1-2.visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
#container{height:1000px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="container">
    <div id="work-col-1-2">
        <p>Text here.</p>
    </div>
</div><!-- end of container div-->
```

Answer (score -1):

change in html

```
id="work-col-1-2" to class="work-col-1-2"
```